# how to append child node using XML with HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have XML parameters at below ; As you can see, the are two "Gateway" node. first one has interface Internal, second one has interface Uplink.

I want to add new **IpRange**, **StartAddress** and **EndAddress** child node. But first of all i need to find Gateway node who has uplink interface and append IpRange parameters here. Like x.x.x.x.

I am new at XML, I am using javascript and HTML DOM.

```
<Gateways>
            <Gateway>
                <Interface>internal</Interface>
                <Subnet>
                    <Gateway>1.1.1.2</Gateway>
                    <Netmask>255.255.255.0</Netmask>
                    <IpAddress>1.1.1.1</IpAddress>
                </Subnet>             
            </Gateway>          
            <Gateway>
                <Interface>uplink</Interface>
                <Subnet>
                    <Gateway>2.2.2.2</Gateway>
                    <Netmask>255.255.255.0</Netmask>
                    <IpAddress>2.2.2.1</IpAddress>
                    <IpRanges>
                        <IpRange>
                            <StartAddress>x.x.x.x</StartAddress>
                            <EndAddress>x.x.x.x</EndAddress>
                        </IpRange>
                           <IpRange>
                            <StartAddress>x.x.x.x</StartAddress>
                            <EndAddress>x.x.x.x</EndAddress>
                        </IpRange>
                    </IpRanges>
                </Subnet>
            </Gateway>
</Gateways>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this JS code mad by XML DOM function:

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      readXML(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "yourFile.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();

  function readXML(xml) {
    var newElement, xmlDoc;
    //New xmlDoc
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    //Looking for the right interface node
    var InterfaceNode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Interface").nodeValue;
    for (let i = 0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Interface").length; i++) {
      //The one with value = 'uplink'
      if (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Interface")[i].nodeValue == 'uplink') {
        var IpRangesNode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("IpRanges")[i];
        //Creating the new node IpRange
        newElement = xmlDoc.createElement("IpRange");
        //Adding 2 new nodes StartAddress and EndAddress both with  x.x.x.x as value
        var newStartAddress = newElement.createElement("StartAddress");
        newStartAddress.nodeValue = "x.x.x.x";
        var newEndAddress = newElement.createElement("EndAddress");
        newEndAddress.nodeValue = "x.x.x.x";
        //Appending to the initial Node
        IpRangesNode.appendChild(newElement);
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope this could help,
Laura.

Comment: Hi Laura, thanks for your effort. I am getting an error like this ; ReferenceError: "XMLHttpRequest" is not defined.   I am using vmware software for development and i think there is no support for XMLHttpRequest library. I have only  XMLManager plugin installed our software :(((  https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.vco_use_plugins.doc_42/GUID-C8E14800-34B2-44D6-A500-4751855C34B8.html

Comment: Hey Legioon, unfortunately, I have no knowledge of vmware software.
My technical solution was designed for JavaScript (pure), but as I see, it has is no compatibility with the framework you are using.
My only suggestion is to close this topic, rephrase your question **specifying** that you need **something working for vmware**, and let the community help you :)